# How to show Vertically scroll Content list in RecyclerView if Portrait mode and Horizontal scroll content list if Landscape Mode?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my Android app I'm using RecyclerView to display a list of content. But the requirement is, the list should scroll vertically if the Screen Mode is Portrait and Horizontally if the Screen Mode is Landscape.To achieve this, I created landscape layout in "layout-land" directory in "main/res" directory. Below is the xml code for "res/layout" and "res/layout-land" directory--

"**res/layout/activity_media**"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/media_bg_color"
                tools:context=".Activities.MediaActivity">

    <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/media_actionbar_layout"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAppInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/app_info"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMediaList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvAppInfo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

"**res/layout-land/activity_media**"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/media_bg_color"
                tools:context=".Activities.MediaActivity">

    <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/media_actionbar_layout"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llParent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAppInfo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="35"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/app_info"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvMediaList"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="65"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is how I mentioned my "MediaActivity" entry in manifest.xml file--

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activities.MediaActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor">
    </activity>
```

Then I override "onConfigurationChanged()" method in my "MediaActivity.java" class to set horizontal layout to RecyclerView if the Screen mode is Landscape and below the my "onConfigurationChanged()" method code--

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        orientationLand = (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? true : false);

        if(orientationLand)
        {
            rvMediaList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is, RecyclerView scrolling list in horizontal fashion, but considering only "res/layout/activity_media" layout even in landscape mode and not the "res/layout-land/activity_media" layout.

Comment: Try removing `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` check if it works

Comment: @SanketPatel Yes I tried this before, android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" after removing this line, system correctly calls "res/layout-land/activity_media", but the problem with this case is "onConfigurationChanged()" method do not gets trigger and I have written the scroll change code in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
                        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
                        // Checks the orientation of the screen
                        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                            madapter = new YourAdapter(this, arrList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
                        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

                            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
                            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                            madapter = new YourAdapter(this, arrList);// for your adapter
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
                        }
```

Also in the manifest file to include the android:configChanges

```
 <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I tried your solution but getting the same result, I mean, in landscape-mode content scroll fashion is getting changed from vertical to horizontal but system still using "res/layout/activity_media" instead of "res/layout-land/activity_media".